# Sharepoint: How to set the permission to edit WSS user profile

Tags: sharepoint, import, wss, profile

I'm running a SharePoint Application on a MOSS 2007 with a form based user authentication without using the MySite feature. So all the settings on the SSP administration site which only concern the user profile on the MySites should normally not affect the user profile of the application as these should be managed from WSS.

But where could I define the settings for the WSS user profiles? At the moment a user can only edit the attributes in his profile which are listed as additional columns for the application's user list (WebsiteAction --> WebisteSettings --> Users and Groups --> All users --> ListSettings). So all other attributes like first, surname, info, title etc. are partly imported form our identity directory (LDAP) but are not editable for the users.

So are there any options to define which of the attributes should be editable for the users and which one should not be? It would also be interesting if there are any options to define which LDAP attributes are mapped to the which WSS profile attribute.

Bye,
Flo

Answer (score 1):

Those things are handled by your shared service provider. So gå there then:

User profiles and properties -> View profile properties

You can also do all sorts of other stuff regarding profiles, mysites, etc there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the view profile properties menu was also the place where I tried to handle my problems. But with our LDAP authentication connector no profiles are imported. The user info are only stored within the user profiles of WSS an therefore the settings in the view profile properties don't affect the settings of the WSS profiles.

So I'm still looking for the place where I can find the settings for the WSS user profile.